# Best practise for initialising list properties?

Tags: c#, initialization

I have a discussion with my co-worker regarding where to initialise list properties in objects. My instinct is to initialise them when the object is constructed:

```
public List<string> Words { get; set; }

public MyClass()
{
    Words = new List<string>();
}
```

Or alternatively

```
public List<string> Words { get; set; } = new List<string>();
```

My co-worker prefers not to do that, and to instead check whether the list is null before accessing it, every single time.

```
if(MyClass.Words == null) Words = new List<string>();
MyClass.Words.Add("foo");
```

Because Words is public it may be accessed from many places, and I feel like the second practise would lead to a lot of duplicated code, with all those null-checks and list creations, which feels "dirty" to me. Is his way better? If so, is there a way in C# to make it more concise?

Comment: I prefer to do one of the first two, if the list doesn't exist after that you should let it throw the exception because something is messing with the class. Alternatively you could force your colleagues into writing immutable classes which would ultimately be the best approach, but not always practical.

Comment: If auto-property-initializers(your second approach) are available(C#6): use that; otherwise use the constructor.

Comment: This question is fairly opinion-based as you´ve already found out. Answering it highly depends on your circumstances.

Comment: I tend to keep the actual list private and only allow access via a public property. The property can then check for null and handle whatever initialization you need.

Comment: @HimBromBeere But what circumstances are relevant here? Opinion-based, sure, but what are the factors to keep in mind?

Comment: If any client will set the property to `null`, you surely have to check for that. We can´t know If this happens in your case. If you can assure that won´t happen the check for null is pretty pointless of course. But from an API-perspective you should check for null.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Well, in this case we're using Entity Framework. I'll take my colleague's word for it that that's a relevant factor.

Comment: But Entity Framework aside, this is a question I had been stumbling on in my own fun projects as well, so I wanted to know the general answers as well.

Comment: The problem with this kind of question is, that there´s no single answer that fits, there may be multiple ones. So how yould you chose the one to accept as "the answer"?

Comment: The most informative one?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I get your point though. Rest assured, I don't ask this kind of question often.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using properties you could do the checking in the `get` method of your property:

```
private List<string> list;
public List<string> Words
{
    get
    {
        list = list ?? new List<string>();
        return list;
    }
}
```

Advantages:

- This would also prevent `null reference` if somebody assigns `null` to your list, if your list is not read-only.
- A problem you may have with constructor is, that you if you overload your constructor have to take care that you initialize your `list`, which you don't have in the property

Answer (score 0):

I would use this as the best of both worlds:

```
private List<string> _words;
public List<string> Words
{
  get
  {
    if(_words == null) 
      _words = new List<string>();

    return _words;
  }
  set
  {
    _words = value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `List<T> Words` being a *property* (exposing non-constant fields is often a *bad practice*) having just `get` accessor, e.g. (C# 7.0 syntax)

```
public List<string> Words => new List<string>();
```

when `Words` is a field you can easily find yourself in trouble when assigning this field:

```
MyClass a = new MyClass();
MyClass b = new MyClass();
...
a.Words = b.Words;

a.Add("abc");

// "abc": a and b share the same list
Console.Write(b.Words.LastOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

With Words being public, I think his way his safer.

Typically, I initialize my lists only once, the way you do, and it always works well for me. However, given that it's public in this case, what if someone sets it null elsewhere?

His way will still work if someone does that, while the way you and I do it will break.

Honestly, after reading this, I'm tempted to use both practices at the same time with public Lists, but I'll probably stick with initializing only once when they're private.

As for a more concise way, the only thing I can think of is with the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms173224(v=vs.90)) `??`:

```
Words = Words ?? new List<string>();
```

Or, if you want something somewhere in the middle, use the [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) (also frequently called the ternary operator) `?:`:

```
Words = Words == null ? new List<string>() : Words;
```